# Почему дрожит текст под absoulte элементом?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/DTX/pen/rLxWVO?editors=1000)

```
position: absolute;
```

Вот записал даже скринкаст, чтобы было понятно, о чем речь.

https://db.tt/c2JMeBZN

При этом при увеличенном масштабе такого не наблюдается. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Какой браузер? У меня ничего не дрожит (Opera 38)

Comment: Хром. Тоже не дрожит.

Comment: Хром последний. При разном масштабе страницы эффект наблюдается по-разному. Иногда отсутствует..
В IE на W10 пытался проверить, но он современный js не переваривает)